# I lose Plex and minidlna about once a day

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi

I have plex and minidlna installed in my raspberry pi, and I watch the content with my LG TV.

I don't know why, but about once a day, I lose both systems on my TV.

I tried to restart services, but it doesn't work.

when I reboot the raspberry, then I can access again the services on my TV.

I don't know how to debug it.

Before, I had no problem, my Raspberry was connected via ethernet, and my TV with wifi.

But I moved, and now, both TV and RPI are connected via wifi.

Private IP are not changing, on neither tv nor rpi.

Why is it happening ? How should I debug this issue ?

Comment: Maybe it is a wifi issue. Check this https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27475/wifi-disconnects-after-period-of-time-on-raspberry-pi-doesnt-reconnect

Comment: I will check it. As far as I remember, once, I found out that internet connection was gone, and I thought about it, but the day after, I had internet, but I had lost dlna servers. I will try to ping each minute and tell you the results !

Comment: also lost ssh connection, but still have internet

Comment: yep, this is weird. I have internet, but no ssh, and when I try ifdown wlan0, it can't find interface

Comment: @GramThanos I tried it several days, and it didn't work. it is still falling once a day aprox.

Comment: @GramThanos but I can confirm it always happens after a deconnection

Comment: Well, it was just a suggestion :P