# My Pi won't reconnect to WiFi if WiFi drops

Tags: wifi, wireless

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2 running Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster). I've been running into a very annoying issue - whenever my home wifi drops (and it does every night because Synology doesn't know how to implement guest networks right) my Pi goes offline and never recovers.

There have been a few posts ([example](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27475/wifi-disconnects-after-period-of-time-on-raspberry-pi-doesnt-reconnect)) but they are quite old and suggest things like /sbin/ifup which are no longer correct.

What is the best way to deal with this? It looks like running `sudo systemctl restart dhcpcd.service` when the network is down as a regular cron job is my best bet, but I wonder if there is a cleaner solution.

To rephrase this: when my home wifi becomes unavailable, the Pi goes offline (expected). When my home wifi recovers, the Pi does not. Is it possible to configure my Pi to automatically recover without the help of a manual cron job?

For the reference, I currently run https://gist.github.com/davidair/64cfb6afa601e4fdd73e30b94c218a2b on a 2 minute cron.

Comment: A correctly configured network setup on the Pi will automatically connect to WiFi. As you have not provided any detail of networking setting or diagnostics it is impossible to say more.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @MatsK - when my home wifi becomes unavailable, the Pi goes offline (expected). When my home wifi recovers, the Pi does not.

Comment: Added clarifications/detail to my post.

Comment: @Milliways - happy to share settings/diagnostics if you can tell me which commands I should run.